# Alamofire 4.0 JSOn parsing Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, alamofire

I new to Alamofire, I was testing out some API. I came across foreign exchange rates. So the JSON file is like this

```
["base": CAD, "date": 2016-12-01, "rates": {
AUD = "1.0097";
BGN = "1.3735";
BRL = "2.57";
CHF = "0.7559";
CNY = "5.1388";
CZK = "19.004";
DKK = "5.2248";
EUR = "0.70225";
GBP = "0.59058";
HKD = "5.7881";
HRK = "5.2985";
HUF = "220.48";
IDR = 10108;
ILS = "2.8607";
INR = "51.009";
JPY = "85.246";
KRW = "871.9400000000001";
MXN = "15.403";
MYR = "3.331";
NOK = "6.2941";
NZD = "1.0539";
PHP = "37.102";
PLN = "3.1374";
RON = "3.1631";
RUB = "47.591";
SEK = "6.8775";
SGD = "1.0657";
THB = "26.616";
TRY = "2.6006";
USD = "0.7462800000000001";
ZAR = "10.504";}]

typealias JSONStandard = [String: AnyObject]

func parseData(JSONData:Data) {
    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
        if let rates = readableJSON["rates"] as? JSONStandard{
            for i in 0..<rates.count {
                let rate = rates[i] as! //Here
            }
            print(rates)
        }
        print(readableJSON)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I was able to get side "rates" but I don't get how I would parse all the data inside the "rates". I thought I would have to save it inside a dictionary. very confused Thanks

Comment: That's not even a valid dataset.  It shouldn't include the semicolon.

Comment: @ElTomato that is actually so true, I just realize that. But I'm sure there is a way around it

Comment: There is no way around it.  You can certainly fix your JSON dataset manually and read it as a Swift file.

Comment: @ElTomato problem is this is from a API, so i might have to look into different ones. OR im just doing everything wrong. hehe http://fixer.io this is the api i used if you want to check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see it's a double value in String, so you need to convert AnyObject to String first, then convert it to Double. You can do it like this (Tested in Swift playground) :

```
import Foundation

typealias JSONStandard = [String: AnyObject]

func parseData(JSONData:Data) {
    do {
        guard let readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as? JSONStandard,
            let ratesJSON = readableJSON["rates"] as? JSONStandard
            else { return }
        print("Readable JSON :")
        print(readableJSON)
        let rates = ratesJSON.flatMap({ (key, value) -> ([String: Double]) in
            guard let value = value as? String, let convertedValue = Double(value) else { return [:] }
            return [key: convertedValue]
        })
        print("Rates :")
        print(rates)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

let jsonString = "{\"base\": \"CAD\", \"date\": \"2016-12-01\", \"rates\": { \"AUD\": \"1.0097\", \"BGN\": \"1.3735\", \"BRL\": \"2.57\"}}"
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
parseData(JSONData: jsonData)
```

Result :

```
Readable JSON :
["base": CAD, "date": 2016-12-01, "rates": {
    AUD = "1.0097";
    BGN = "1.3735";
    BRL = "2.57";
}]
Rates :
[("BGN", 1.3734999999999999), ("AUD", 1.0097), ("BRL", 2.5699999999999998)]
```

Comment: Is it possible for you tell me the detail usage of guard?

Comment: @J.Kim1205 guard is like an if, but it will only check if the condition is true or not, it's also called bouncer pattern. So it will work like this guard condition else { // your code and return }, if the condition is true, it will go to the next line, if not it will go to else block there is also a good explanation here -> http://ericcerney.com/swift-guard-statement/

Comment: jsonString.data? where is this from

Comment: @J.Kim1205 Oh that's Swift 3 syntax, it should be jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) in Swift 2, but I see you are using Swift 3 right?

Comment: I meant by the .flatmap part never seen it before

Comment: @J.Kim1205 read this : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/

Answer (score 0):

You have to save it into an array of Double:

```
var yourArray = [Double]()

    for i in 0..<rates.count {
        let rate = rates[i] as! Double
        print(rate)
        yourArray.append(rate)
    }

print(yourArray.description)
```

Comment: that mean ill be only saving my double values, I want to save my string too